# Deletar registro do banco de dados com ajax+spring boot+thymeleaf

Tags: java, ajax, bootstrap-3, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Boa tarde!
Estou tentando excluir um item na minha view, que está em uma tabela do bootstrap. Estou usando thymeleaf + bootstrapno frontend. A ideia é pegar o id e passar pra uma janela modal do bootstrap e através da modal excluir o registro no banco. Mas não estou conseguindo passar o id pra função ajax excluir o registro. Alguém pode me ajudar? x.x

Segue os trechos de código ->

https://hastebin.com/acuyikufum.xml

Answer (score 0):

> Caso não tenha resolvido ainda, eu fiz assim vê se ajuda.

```
$('#confirmacaoExclusaoModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {
var button = $(event.relatedTarget);

var Codigo = button.data('codigo');
var Nome = button.data('nome');

var modal = $(this);
var form = modal.find('form');
var action = form.data('url-base');
if (!action.endsWith('/')) {
    action += '/';
}
form.attr('action', action + Codigo);

modal.find('.modal-body span').html('Tem certeza que deseja excluir :  

<strong>' + Nome + '</strong>?');
});
```

Comment: Obrigado, vou testar assim que possível. Desculpa a demora pra visualizar. Assim que eu testar dou um retorno. Valeu!!!